# Как сделать Слайдер

Tags: html, css

Помогите сделать отображение номера слайда и их общего количества.
http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancymoves/#&slider1=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После `<div class="mb-controls">`
Вставить `<div id="num"></div><div id="nums"></div>`

Добавить в скрипт, для определения кол-ва слайдов
`$('#nums').text($('#slider-one .mb-panel').length);`

Для определения текущего слайда:

```
var num = $('#num');
    var i = $('#slider-one .mb-panel').filter(function(index) {
        if ($(this).css('font-size') == '16px') {
            return index;                       
        }
    }).index();
    num.text(i);
```

Или номер текущего слайда определить так:

```
var num = $('#num');
var i = $('#slider-one div.mb-panel[style*=1em]').index();
num.text(i);
```

Но лучше всего добавить активному слайду класс, например `active`, тогда проще искать индекс элемента активного.